# How do I change the color of text when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am working on a menu for my HTML class, at school, and I was trying to figure out how I could make it so my h1 and h2 text change to the color white when they reach the top of the page, which with the background image, is dark at the top. Below is my code. The h1 and h2 tags are the only ones I want to have change.

```js
/*
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var light_pos = $('#white_div').offset().top;
    var light_height = $('#white_div').height();
    var menu_pos = $('.NavigationButton').offset().top;
    var menu_height = $('.NavigationButton').height();
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log('light', light_pos);
    console.log('menu', menu_pos);
    console.log('scroll', scroll);

    if (menu_pos > light_pos && menu_pos < (light_pos + light_height)) {
      $('.NavigationButton').addClass('menu_black');
      $('.NavigationButton').removeClass('menu_white');
    } else {
      $('.NavigationButton').removeClass('menu_black');
      $('.NavigationButton').addClass('menu_white');
    }

  })
})
*/
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  border: 4px;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

b {
  font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive;
}

div {
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

sup {
  font-family: Verderna, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.NavigationButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  z-index: 99999;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: inherit;
}

.menu_white {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu_black {
  color: #000;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://bestanimations.com/media/beverages/405618319drink-animated-gif-16.gif');
  /*Image sorce*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*If changed to "repeat", image will repeat*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /*Does your image stay in one spot, or does it move as you scroll?*/
  background-size: cover;
  /*The resolution of the image*/
}
```

```html
<title>Big Surf Island: Beverages Menu</title>
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<!--Below is all the code for the fonts that I've used. All custom fonts used came from Google Fonts. [fonts.google.com]-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="2021_04_06_0fb_Kleki.png">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght&#64;500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nothing+You+Could+Do&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nothing+You+Could+Do&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Homemade+Apple&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Background image for website  -->
<h2 style='color:white'>Pick a drink, any drink!</h2>

<h1>Non-Alchoholic drinks</h1>


<!--1st Menu Item-->
<div>

  <h3>Fountain Drinks--------------------1.99</h3>
  <b>Choose any of our fountain drink, in any flavor you want!
    <img height=132px; width=320px; src="https://img1.mashed.com/img/gallery/why-fountain-drinks-taste-different/intro-1588447053.jpg"></b>
</div>

<!--2nd Menu Item-->
<div>
  <h3>Iced Tea, Tea, &amp; Coffee 2.95</h3>
  <b>Pick your choice of cold or hot tea, any flavor, or coffee, made just the way you like it.
    <img height=140.625px; width=250px; src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F12%2F2020%2F05%2F11%2Fcoffee-tea-GettyImages-930798200.jpg&amp;q=85"></b>
</div>

<!--3rd Menu Item-->
<h1>Drinks only for Mom and Dad<br> (Valid ID must be presented to<br> waitor / waitress to show you<br> are older than 21)</h1>
<div>
  <h3>Beer and Wine---------------5.99</h3>
  <b>Choose your poison, but don't overdo it.
    <!--Look I just copied the image link.-->
    <img height=208px; width=282px; src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"></b>
</div>
<!--Link back to menu homepage-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So your commented code is your attempt?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes. It's what I searched up on Google.